# Defining New Environments using a Command

Tags: macros, environments

I would be able to do something like the following:

Instead of having the following, where I repeat the same code many many times:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\newenvironment{enum1}{\begin{enumerate}[1.]}{\end{enumerate}}
\newenvironment{enuma}{\begin{enumerate}[a.]}{\end{enumerate}}
...
```

I would like to be able to "automate" it somewhat, eg.:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\newEnum}[1]{\newenvironment{enum#1}{\begin{enumerate}[#1.]}{\end{enumerate}}
\newEnum{1}
\newEnum{a}
...
```

Of course, this doesn't compile, or I wouldn't be here asking.

Is there a way to do this, or am I stuck copy and pasting and making the necessary changes?

Comment: You're short a close brace `}` in your definition of `\newEnum`. Apart from that, it works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For lists I'd recommend you use the `enumitem` package and use the `newlist` facility that is built in.

[image]

If you have many of these you could use

```
\newcommand{\DefineNewList}[3]{%
    % #1 = name
    % #2 = max depth
    % #3 = label
    \newlist{#1}{enumerate}{#2}
    \setlist[#1]{label*=#3}
}%
```

but I don't see much value in that.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{enumOne}{enumerate}{2}
\setlist[enumOne]{label*=\arabic*.}

\newlist{enumA}{enumerate}{2}
\setlist[enumA]{label*=\alph*.}

\begin{document} 

\begin{enumOne}
    \item First item in enumOne
    \item Second item in enumOne
\end{enumOne}

\begin{enumA}
    \item First item in enumA
    \item Second item in enumA
\end{enumA}

\end{document}
```

---

### Code `Repeated Usage`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newcommand{\DefineNewList}[3]{%
    % #1 = name
    % #2 = max depth
    % #3 = label
    \newlist{#1}{enumerate}{#2}
    \setlist[#1]{label*=#3}
}%

\DefineNewList{enumOne}{2}{\arabic*.}
\DefineNewList{enumA}{2}{\alph*.}

\begin{document} 

\begin{enumOne}
    \item First item in enumOne
    \item Second item in enumOne
\end{enumOne}

\begin{enumA}
    \item First item in enumA
    \item Second item in enumA
\end{enumA}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\newcommand\newEnum[1]{%
  \newenvironment{enum#1}{\enumerate[#1.]}{\endenumerate}}
\newEnum{1}
\newEnum{a}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item foo
\item bar
\end{enumerate}

\begin{enum1}
\item foo
\item bar
\end{enum1}

\begin{enuma}
\item foo
\item bar
\end{enuma}

\end{document}
```

However, using package `enumitem` has some more possibilities.